# How to add / multiply / relate 2 matrixes with different dimensions

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, linear-algebra

Matrix `A` has fixed dimensions of `1 x 768` and `B` has `n x m` dimensions, where `n, m` are variables.

Obviously they can't be used to be added or multiplied directly, so I was wondering is there a mathematical way to create a relation within this 2 matrixes? By relation I mean any way that makes possible to add them, or that let take a step forward to another process. I'm in a deadend and cannot escape through this.

[image: img]

Comment: It is unclear what is being asked here, as there are no sensible semantics for adding or multiplying arbitrarily-dimensioned matrices. It looks like some kind of XY-problem, so it would be best to take a step back and specify what task is supposed to be accomplished here. For example, is this a question about a system of equations which can be either underdetermined or overdetermined?

Comment: @njuffa i want to incorporate this 1 x 768 matrix to a system with that variable shape

Comment: To what purpose?

Comment: @njuffa i don't have a specific purpose since I don't know what process can be used. I would rather know what can I do with those matrixes and then think what I want to do that  the other. It's a bit odd but in my project it's the way it has to be done. I'll upload a picture for better understanding!

Comment: You can perform a limited set of operations on matrices of different sizes, see [Matrix addition/multiplication with different sizes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1232835/matrix-addition-multiplication-with-different-sizes/1232846) for a short explanation.